# My Java Sieve code is slow and not scaling at the expected time complexity

Tags: java, multithreading, time-complexity, sieve-of-eratosthenes, sieve

I have wrote the following 'segmented sieve' program in Java. It take a range of numbers to sieve, crosses out composite numbers using the 'sieving primes' (primes arraylist variable) then returns the prime numbers that have not been crossed out. Here is the code:

```
public ArrayList<Integer> sieveWorker(int start, int last, ArrayList<Integer> primes) {

    System.out.println("Thread started for range: " + start + "-" + last);
    ArrayList<Integer> nonPrimes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> primeNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    //numbers to be sieved
    for (int i = start; i <= last; i += 2) {
        numbers.add(i);
    }

    //identifies composites of the sieving primes, then stores them in an arraylist
    for (int i = 0; i < primes.size(); i++) {

        int head = primes.get(i);

        if ((head * head) <= last) {
            if ((head * head) >= start) {
                for (int j = head * head; j <= last; j += head * 2) {
                    nonPrimes.add(j);
                }
            } else {
                int k = Math.round((start - head * head) / (2 * head));
                for (int j = (head * head) + (2 * k * head); j <= last; j += head * 2) {
                    nonPrimes.add(j);
                }
            }
        }

    }

    numbers.removeAll(nonPrimes);
    System.out.println("Primes: " + numbers);
    return numbers;
}
```

My problem is that it's very slow and performing at a time complexity of o(n^3) instead of the expected time of complexity of o(n log log n). I need suggestions on optimisation and correcting its time complexity.

Comment: This is actually something for code review. But for starters, **stop recomputing head** do one time `int headToThePower = head*head`  and use that on every occasion of `head*head`. The same goes for `head * 2`. Also you might want to use a streams here so you'll benefit of parallel processing.

Comment: Using an array instead of lists might speed things up.

Comment: this is *not* for CodeReview, because this code is not working as expected, as stated by the OP (re the complexity). yay for actually measuring the empirical orders of growth!!

Answer (score 1):

The culprit is the `numbers.removeAll(nonPrimes)` call which for each number in `numbers` (and there are *O(n)* of them) searches through all of `nonPrimes` potentially (and there are *O(n log log last)* of them) to check the membership (and `nonPrimes` is non-sorted, too).  *n* is the length of `numbers`,  `n = last - start`.

So instead of *O(1)*  **marking** of each non-prime you have an *O(n log log last)* actual removal of it, for each of the *O(n)* of them. Hence the above *O(n^2)* operations overall.

One way to overcome this is to use simple arrays, and *mark* the non-primes. Removal destroys the direct address capability. If use it at all, the operations must be *on-line*, with close to *O(1)* operations per number. This can be achieved by making the non-primes be a *sorted* list, then to remove them from numbers iterate along both in linear fashion. Both tasks easiest done with arrays, again.

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation

```
numbers.removeAll(nonPrimes);
```

must **find** elements. That's basically *contains* and *contains* on `ArrayList` is slow, `O(n)`.

It iterates the whole list from left to right and removes the matching elements. And it does this for every element in your `nonPrimes` collection. So you will get a complexity of `O(n * |nonPrimes|)` just for the `removeAll` part.

---

### Solution

There is an easy fix, exchange your data-structure. Structures like `HashSet` where made for `O(1)` *contains* queries. Since you only need to `add` and `removeAll` on `numbers`, consider using a `HashSet` instead, which runs both in `O(1)` (ammortized).

Only change in code:

```
Set<Integer> numbers = new HashSet<>();
```

Another possibility is to do some algorithmic changes. You can avoid the `removeAll` in the end by marking the elements while you collect them. The advantage is that you could use arrays then. The big advantage then is that you avoid the boxed `Integer` class and directly run on the primitives `int` which are faster and don't consume as much space. Check the answer of @Will_Ness for details on this approach.

---

### Note

Your `primeNumbers` variable is never used in your method. Consider removing it.